# How can you mock the methods from a class if you have no control over the class?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, xunit

I'm using Xunit and Moq for unit testing. So far I was able to succesfully mock and test methods from interfaces.
But how am I supposed to mock and test the methods of a class that I have no control over. The class has no interface and the methods are not virtual.

I looked into Type Mock Isolator, but I could not make that work, and also that is not a feasible solution because it's paid and only has a 14 day trial, and I need to do this long term.

What are my options?

Comment: There are many free alternatives: [Prig](https://urasandesu.github.io/Prig/), [Pose](https://github.com/tonerdo/pose), [Harmony](https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony), [MethodRedirect](https://github.com/spinico/MethodRedirect), [Ionad.Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Ionad)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a wrapper for the dependency. You don't need to test the implementation of code you didn't write. Mock the dependency wrapper with the anticipated or hypothetical outputs.

```
public sealed class SomeBadDependency
{
    public int CalculateSuperSecretValue(int inputX, int inputY)
    {
        return Math.Max(inputX, inputY);
    }
}

public interface IDependencyWrapper
{
    int CalculateSuperSecretValue(int inputX, int inputY);
}

public sealed class DependencyWrapper : IDependencyWrapper
{
    private readonly SomeBadDependency _someBadDependency;

    public DependencyWrapper(SomeBadDependency someBadDependency)
    {
        _someBadDependency = someBadDependency;
    }
    
    public int CalculateSuperSecretValue(int inputX, int inputY)
    {
        return _someBadDependency.CalculateSuperSecretValue(inputX, inputY);
    }
}

public sealed class YourCode
{
    private readonly IDependencyWrapper _dependencyWrapper;

    public YourCode(IDependencyWrapper dependencyWrapper)
    {
        _dependencyWrapper = dependencyWrapper;
    }

    public decimal CalculateYourValue(decimal inputX, decimal inputY)
    {
        return _dependencyWrapper.CalculateSuperSecretValue((int) inputX, (int) inputY);
    }
}
```