# Mock methods of a class not given by DI

Tags: .net-core, moq, xunit

I have a class I am trying to test. The class constructor has a class that is injected and another class that is initialized in the constructor. The second class comes from an external source.

```cs
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly ILogger<MyClass> _logger;
    private readonly MavlinkParse _mavlink;

    public MyClass(ILogger<MyClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _mavlink = new MavlinkParse();
    }
}
```

Later I have a method where I call the `_mavlink` methods based on a condition. I want to somehow mock the methods, or better yet just "spy" on them and know which was called.

The method:

```cs
public SomeMethod(input)
{
    if(cond)
        return _mavlink.method1(lots of params);
    return _mavlink.method2(lots of params);
}
```

I know how to mock the logger using `xunit` and `moq`. What I am stuck on is how to test `SomeMethod()`.

I come from the angular world, where I could easily solve this issue with a spy, and `expect(method1Spy).toHaveBeenCalled()` would be perfect. I would also be able to settle for the idea of having `method1()` return a hard-coded value, ignoring params, and check that that came through

How can I achieve this effect in c# dotnet core using xunit and moq?

Comment: Pass the `MavlinkParse` instance through the constructor so it uses DI. Any other solution is going to be brittle.

Comment: Thanks...
I did not write the code, I am just writing the tests. But I can speak to the head developer and see if that is an option

Comment: I agree with the injection comment. However as a unit, you could simply test that the output of SomeMethod meets the expectation of the various inputs.

Comment: So I ended up using [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65833573/14492841) in a workaround